# CSHTML editable fields for multiple models in one to many database model

Tags: razor

I created a form that pushes data to two tables in a database.  The header information of the form pushes as a single entry in one table and then as multiple lines on the other table that reference the entry on the first table.  One to many relationship.

I need to be able to edit the information in the form.  I'm able get the header information to render into editable fields, but I'm not able to for the multiple line level information.

Here is my model:

```
using CustomerPortal.Identity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CustomerPortal.Models
{
    public class EventViewModel
    {
        public string CustomerPONumber { get; set; }
        public string SupplierReferenceNumber { get; set; }
        public string CarrierProNumber { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CarrierEventItem> CarrierEventItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The IEnumerable references the `CarrierEventItems` table.

On the CSHTML page I am able to render the event fields as a editable:

```
@model EventViewModel

<div class="list-item">
    <h3>Cust PO Number</h3>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerPONumber)
</div>

 @foreach (var carrierEventItem in @Model.CarrierEventItems)
     {

          <div class="list-item">
              <h3>Customer Item</h3>
              <ul>
                  <li>
                     Customer Item Number: @carrierEventItem.CustomerItemNumber
                  </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
     }
```

I'm haven't been able to get the `CarrierEventItem` fields to be editable, and I've just been able to display them.

Any help on the html I have to do would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this pretty easily, rather than entering each field in a separate html div, Razor automatically renders the fields as editable:

```
    <div class="col-12">
        @foreach (var carrierEventItem in @Model.CarrierEventItems)
            {

                <div class="list-item">
                    <h3>Customer Item</h3>

                    @Html.EditorFor(m => carrierEventItem)

                </div>
            }
     </div>
```